# TypeLoadException was unhandled

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, typeloadexception

While running **WPF** application after click submit button thrown below error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll

Additional information: Method 'DeleteConfigPanel' in type 'GEMMF.ServiceProvider.GEMMFServiceProvider'
from assembly 'GEMMF.ServiceProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
```

How to solve this. Please help me.

Comment: As mentioned in error description, check for Method "DeleteConfigPanel" in the Type GEMMF.ServiceProvider.GEMMFServiceProvider from assembly 'GEMMF.ServiceProvider'

Comment: I did't understand. I find DeleteConfigPanel method in my entire solution but can't find that function name.

Comment: Also, try deleting the obj folder and rebuilding the solution.

Comment: I tried to delete obj folder and rebuild but getting same error

Comment: please help me to solve this. Method 'DeleteConfigPanel' in type 'GEMMF.ServiceProvider.GEMMFServiceProvider' from assembly 'GEMMF.ServiceProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.